# Patch a glyph into a font from another font

Tags: fonts, unicode, patch

I have a monaco font patched for powerline that I downloaded from [this repository](https://github.com/powerline/fonts). Now for licensing issue there are no free version of this font. Anyway, I use tmux which have `U+2502` as a separator for vertical split. Now, the monaco font that I have doesn't have this glyph.

I have another font, official latest version of [Inconsolata](https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/ofl/inconsolata) that has a beautiful version of this glyph. I ran into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821973/tmux-borders-are-drawn-with-dashed-lines-how-can-i-change-them-to-continuous-li/26881325#26881325?newreg=0f2e88391108496daea74bea6abdf0f6) from a while ago where one of the answers was to patch the font with that glyph manually with fontforge or similar font editor.

How do I just add one glyph to one font from another font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it with fontforge on Windows (already installed), it's pretty straight forward.

- Open fontforge with the source font, scroll down until you find `U+2502`.
- Right click on the glyph -> *Copy*
- Open another instance of fontforge with the target font, scroll down to the empty slot for `U+2502`
- Right click -> *Paste*
- Select *File -> Generate Fonts (Ctrl+Shift+G)* in the menu, enter a new font name, select *True Type*, click *Generate* and click away some warnings.
- Repeat for each font type (regular, bold, italic, ...)

[image: modified Inconsolata]

For testing I used Arial.ttf as source font and inserted the glyph into Inconsolata.ttf of your second link (didn't have this glyph).

[image: Generate Fonts dialog]

Comment: Yeah. I should've at least checked out fontforge before I asked this question. I had done it myself within an hour of posting this question. Thanks.